# What is the difference between "entanglement distillation" and "entanglement purification"?

Tags: entanglement, state-distillation

To my understanding, entanglement distillations is transformation of several copies of weakly entangled states into fewer copies of more strongly entangled states using local operations and classical communication.
My question is, what is the difference between "entanglement distillation" and "entanglement purification"?
I've checked some papers, but I thought these words are used interchangeably.

Comment: They *are* probably used interchangeably. There's some differences between protocols which work on a small number of copies (e.g. recurrence protocols) and asymptotically (hashing protocols), but I don't think this is strictly reflected in the terminology you ask about.

Comment: Thank you. I'm relieved to hear your answer.
I'll look into the protocols you mentioned.